# Is there a simple way to include a missing reference to an assembly in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.
In most solutions I have lots of projects which reference each other.

It's quite time consuming to always add the reference manually.

Is there a simple way (either built-in or via extension) to include a missing reference to an assembly in the own solution similar to the way missing `using`s are resolved?

Comment: You are doing something very wrong when adding a project reference is "time consuming".  It never takes me more than 3 seconds and I rarely do it more often than once a week.  Very hard to guess what that might be, you'll have to talk more about your typical workflow.

Comment: @HansPassant The time consuming part if finding out in which of the 20+ projects, most of them starting with the same letters, the respective class is.

Comment: Simply use Object Browser, type or paste the class name in the search box.  That's ~6 seconds instead of 3.

Answer (score 7):

Resharper does exactly this.  If there's a class that is defined in another project in the solution, it offers you to reference that class and import the namespace.  All you do is press "Alt+Enter, Enter" to pop up context menu and select the first option.

Comment: If there is only one option you don't even need the second enter ;-) :-P <3 ReSharper!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, resharper will be a good solution for your request. but if you are looking for a free visual studio extension that does the same you can use 'WoVS Quick Add Reference' extension.

Some info: http://ihadthisideaonce.com/2011/07/29/recommended-wovs-quick-add-reference/

Download link: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dc06b54c-b6c4-4cf5-8203-a09c6979e881/

I hope it supports your questions..

Comment: I'll have a look at it on Monday

Comment: "This item is not yet published." says the VS extensions page. :(

Comment: Sounds like you have no option other than resharper if that the case :/

Answer (score 0):

This extension at least offers a way to add references to GAC assemblies

[visual studio gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9791378b-404c-4d0f-bbda-01caa7080228?SRC=VSIDE)

But it requires CodeRush and so also isn't a free choice.